# How do I get a printable version of my Nextcloud calendar?

Tags: printing, calendar

I'm looking at the web interface for Nextcloud and I cannot find any option to get a printable version of my calendar. I could definitely just print the webpage, but that is somewhat inflexible as it does not let me choose how many days the printed calendar should span, or let me get rid of the graphical user interface surrounding it. What more printer-friendly methods are there to print my Nextcloud calendar? I don't mind if they involve downloading/installing an application (though in my case it would have to be usable in Linux).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the only work-around I have found for this issue is to use the CalDAV address to link to another calendar app that supports printing. Super lame, I know.